# Merge two search functions for custom post type

Tags: wp-query, functions

In addition to the site-wise search. I have a custom search for a certain post type and with different ordering than the global search. Here are the two function, which works. I wonder if those two can be merged into one, or simplified if possible?

```
function _s_staff_search($template) {
    global $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->is_search && 'staff' === get_query_var('post_type')) {
        $template = get_template_part('template-parts/staff-search');
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include', '_s_staff_search');

function _s_staff_query($query) {
    if ($query->is_search() && 'staff' === get_query_var('post_type')) {
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'name';
        $query->query_vars['order'] = 'ASC';
    }
}
add_filter('parse_query', '_s_staff_query');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your functions are already simple enough, and secondly, the functions do different things:

- `_s_staff_query()` filters the posts query variables and the function has to run *before* `WP_Query` queries the database.
- `_s_staff_search()` filters the search results template and the function has to run *after* `WP_Query` queries the database.

So just keep them independent.